# How does "this" actually provide a Context from an Activity when used in for example an Intent(this, ClassName.class)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I know how to use `intent`s practically, however I don't really understand

1. What really happens when you write `this` and pass it as a parameter in a method from an `Activity`.

I know that the reserved keyword `this` in java refers to an object. I double checked what it really does with the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

From the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) they explain that the `this` keywords references tot the `Context` instance that is the super-class of the Activity class.

> this is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context

I have no idea how this precisely works. All I know is that in xml I define a `onClick` listener which specifies a method name, and because the layout is inflated from a specific class I think that it could be possible that an object of the inflated class is created at a certain time and the `this` refers to this `Activity` object. Is it then downcasted to it superclass `Context` automatically by automatic type conversion?

Comment: Your question has all the answers too. It's hard to see where your confusion is.

Comment: Well, I am glad all the assumptions I made turned out right then. Guess I have to look into which part of the OS created the activity class object for me and how it does that so my understanding of the language is greater than it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Activity page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

```
ava.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

We also need to note that Context is an `abstract class`, so we need to use some implementation because it is imposible to create an instance of an abstract class in java. And on this [Context page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) you can see all the 'Known Indirect Subclasses': It is not only Activity that can be **used as a Context**.

So Activity extends Context => [Wiki Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))

> What really happens when you write this and pass it as a parameter in
>   a method from an Activity.

[Passing subclass or superclass object to method (expecting a superclass object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836644/passing-subclass-or-superclass-object-to-method-expecting-a-superclass-object)

Answer (score 1):

This is basic principle of OOP.

`Activity` object **is** `Context` object because `Activity` class inherits from `Context` class and as such it can be used directly anywhere `Context` instance is required.